# Oracle 11g Query to insert first day and last day of the week for consecutive 16 weeks

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a temporary table and have to insert the first day of the week starting from Monday and last day of the week as Sunday.The data inside the table should look like

```
BUCKET_ID START_DATE END_DATE
1         13-MAR-17  19-Mar-17
2         20-MAR-17  26-Mar-17
3         27-Mar-17  02-APr-17
```

Comment: The conditions you provided are not sufficient to completely determine the output. What should be the first week, or the last week, or what should be the first Monday from which all the other dates in the table are calculated? Or are you allowed to fill the table with ANY 16 consecutive weeks?

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO your_temp_table
SELECT LEVEL,
       TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + NUMTODSINTERVAL( 7 * (LEVEL - 1), 'DAY' ),
       TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + NUMTODSINTERVAL( (7 * LEVEL) - 1, 'DAY' )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 16;
```

*Note: You could just use* `TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + 7 * (LEVEL - 1)` *but I prefer to be explicit that the query is adding an interval which is a multiple of days.*

The `IW` format mask will truncate to ISO Week, which always starts on a Monday regardless of the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` or `NLS_TERRITORY` settings. If you use the `DAY` format mask and someone changes those settings (or runs the query internationally) then your query may not do what you intended it to do.

Comment: Never really used format masks in TRUNC so thanks for educating. However, why use 'IW' instead of 'DAY' ?

Comment: @BriteSponge `IW` will truncate to ISO Week - which always starts on a Monday regardless of the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` or `NLS_TERRITORY` settings. If you use `DAY` and someone changes those settings (or runs the query internationally) then your query will not do what you intended it to do.

Comment: Thanks for that. You think you know stuff and then - BAM - you didn't after all.

Comment: @BriteSponge As an example, try running `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'UNITED KINGDOM';` then `SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'DAY' ) FROM DUAL` and compare it to running `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'AMERICA';` first.